# Google sheets Forumla - How to get unique sum for each row using data from 2 columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There are 2,827 rows in Column A
Each have a different USD Dollar Value.

Column B Has the same value of 4.99 for the 2,827 rows.

Whats the formula to get the unique sum for the 2,827 rows in column C?

Column D has the same rate of 20.00% for the 2,827 rows

What is the formula to get the grand total?

[image: EXAMPLE IMAGE]

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried so far. Also it looks as though E2=C2+0.2 ... should that be C2+C2*0.2, if it's a percentage added?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to add all the total values together.
If you want to have a Grand Total below, you should write just:
=sum(e2:e5) in your e6 cell.

But if you want to add more rows and keep your grand total in the same place, it's useful to have it on top. Like on the picuture:

=sum(e2:e) means that it adds all the cell values found between row 2 and end of this column.

[image]

It's also strange that you add 20% in column D. This way you add 0.2 to each value. If this is your intention and insurance costs 20 cents, it's ok. But if you want to add 20% to subtotal value, you should put =c2*1.2 in insurance column.

Comment: Hey krzy, I ended up figuring it out pretty quick after I posted the question.  I broke it down into two parts.    For adding all of column A Rows with the fee value in column b. I used =arrayformula(a2:a2827+b2) which populated all of column c rows with the value. Then I created a similar formula to implement the %  and  formatted the column as $   i was just over thinking it.